# SSH config - same host but different keys and usernames

Tags: ssh, git, github

I've set up two GitHub accounts, but I can't get ssh keys to work correctly. I've tried various configs.

---

```
Host github_username1
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_1
    User username1
Host github_username2
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_2
    User username2
```

`git push`:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

---

Works for username1:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_1
    User username1
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_2
    User username2
```

`git push` at username2's repo:

```
ERROR: Permission to username2/repo.git denied to username1.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

---

I've also tried `git push` with both `IdentityFile` and `User` settings under same `Host`. The output is the same as with the last config.

I think git automatically searches for Host "github.com" because the remote is such. It is said that Host can be anything you want (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828682). Is there any way to change what Host from ssh config should specific repo use?

It would be ideal if I could solve this just from ~/.ssh/config.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, **only** the section headers (the `Host` or `Match` lines) are searched for – everything else is only applied as a setting. In other words, if you connect to `foo@bar.com`, OpenSSH will only look for a section titled `Host bar.com`.

So if you have `Host github_username2`, you must use this exact same "hostname" in your Git remotes as well. OpenSSH will not find this section if you use git@github.com.

However, that is not what causes authentication failures. When connecting to GitHub via SSH, you must use `git` as your username – the server will recognize you based on the key alone. (In other words, the "git@" in "git@github.com" is actually the SSH username that GitHub uses – not some kind of URI scheme.)

So a correct SSH configuration would be:

```
Host github_username1
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_1
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github_username2
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_2
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

with this Git configuration:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = github_username1:username2/repo.git
```

(It doesn't matter where you specify the SSH username – you can have `git@` in the URL, or you can have `User git` in .ssh/config, or both.)

---

Alternative Git configuration to automatically switch accounts depending on repo path:

1. Create a file `~/.config/git/config.user1` containing:

   ```
   [url "github_username1:"]
       insteadOf = git@github.com:
   ```
2. Create a `config.user2` file that's the same except with "github_username2".
3. In your main `~/.config/git/config` file, tell Git to "include" one of the two files depending on which directory you're at:

   ```
   [includeIf "gitdir:~/projects/"]
       path = ~/.config/git/config.user1

   [includeIf "gitdir:~/src/work/"]
       path = ~/.config/git/config.user2
   ```
4. Now, whenever you're at `~/src/work/`, cloning anything from `git@github.com:[etc]` will automatically rewrite the URL to `github_username2:[etc]`.

Comment: In some cases you might need to add `IdentitiesOnly=yes` on each `host` section to make sure ssh will only pick the chosen identity file and don't default / try anything else..

Comment: This solution is not foolproof, when you have submodules you are stuck with a broken .gitconfig

Comment: Your local .git/config can use `[url ...] insteadOf = ...` to automagically substitute the real submodule URLs with your customized ones.

Comment: @TCB13 your hint about `IdentitiesOnly` just saved me after I couldn't figure out why my config hasn't been working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `IdentitiesOnly` was also required for me. Should be added to the main answer!

Comment: An alternative to this answer is to use [SSH config matchers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691210/matching-both-user-and-host-simultaneously-in-ssh-config), which allows matching a unique host + user combination.